# firebase instance in constructor crashes site

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, constructor

I am trying to work with data using realtime database firebase in Angular. I tried to follow tutorial but my site won't load after putting `public database: Database` in constructor. What is happening here? Why does it not load with that line? Rest of the code I tried to make:
HTML:

```
<form #RegisterForm = "ngForm" (ngSubmi)="registerUser(RegisterForm.value)">
    <input type="text" ngModel id="username" name="username">
    <input type="text" ngModel id="username" name="username">
    <input type="text" ngModel id="username" name="username">
    <input type="submit" ngModel id="saveData" name="signup_submit" value="Register User">
</form>
```

TS:

```
  constructor( private cartService: CartInfoService, public database: Database){}
  
  registerUser(value: any){

    set(ref(this.database, 'users/'+value.username),{
      username: value.username,
      first_name: value.first_name,
      profile_pic: value.last_name
    })
    alert('user created!')
  }
```

IMPORTS:
`import { getDatabase, set, update, ref, onValue, Database} from "firebase/database";`

Comment: Depends on what kind of error you are getting. It does not load probably because adding thing to a constructor will trigger a [dependency injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) mechanism, and you didnt register a `provider` to fulfill the DI. Things there are a bit more complicated than you think.

Comment: Well the site just turns blank, thats the error. I am just trying to connect the site with database to fetch data from that db instead of fetching from local json. Maybe I am trying to connect it in wrong way?

Comment: There should be some output from the angular CLI, check it to see if there is any compilation errors, or try to restart it. Basically you will need to perform some additional steps to be able to retrieve a Database from the DI container. Honestly, I'd recommend to use the [AngularFire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire) library over plain firebase. It ships with DI configured.